# How to launch a LWUIT form from a LCDUI form?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lcdui, lwuit-form

The question has been indirectly spoken about in some of the earlier questions but i havent seen anything decisive about it..

I am currently using this piece of code to show a LWUIT form inside `CommandAction` implementation.

```
public void commandAction(Command cmnd, Item item) {

if (item == LogIn && cmnd == maincommand) {
RechForm = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("Basefook");
            HttpRequestHandler handler = new HttpRequestHandler();
            HTMLComponent htmlc = new HTMLComponent(handler);
            htmlc.setPage("http://facebook.com");
            RechForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, htmlc);
            com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);
            RechForm.show();

}

}
```

Currently it doesnt bring up the form ,nor does it crash.

well if thats not possible then can you suggest a workaround to some sort of browser control for MIDP based of lcdui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.It now works.Just put the `com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);` into `startApp()`
and change

```
RechForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, htmlc);
```

to

```
RechForm.addComponent(htmlc);
```