# Can typical j2me API(LCDUI) and LWUIT combined together

Tags: java-me, autocomplete, lwuit, lcdui

My doubt is I building an **J2ME location based application as a my final year project** which is totally built using J2ME API like high level UI (Form) and low level UI (Canvas). Now i want to use the LWUIT API's to make few changes in high level UI and implement **autocomplete functionality to textfield to select desired place name by user according he/she type** which am not able to do it.

"To Places autocomplete I am using **Google Place API - Places Autocomplete feature**"

**I am already created my whole design in LCDUI; because of autocomplete functionality now I can't re-create my entire design in LWUIT**

Is it possible to combine both LCDUI and LWUIT components together?
i.e. use both LWUIT and Canvas together in an application?

Comment: I would recommend entering the string `j2me use lwuit and lcdui together?` into the Google search engine.  Doing so brings up a handful of relevant resources.

Comment: yesss I searched by this keyword but it doesn't gave me something useful result.....

Answer (score 1):

LWUIT components are drawn to Canvas and LWUIT draws the whole Canvas area. You can not mix LWUIT components with LCDUI ones.

Comment: Still LWUIT will assume that nothing else will draw on the Canvas. You can give it a try but I think it will create more problems than it solves

Answer (score 1):

It is possible somehow to mix LCDUI and LWUIT but its not straight forward. I know there is access to some LCDUI components through some wrappers in LWUIT. You can check this post : [How to launch a LWUIT form from a LCDUI form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893318/how-to-launch-a-lwuit-form-from-a-lcdui-form)

It seems he has an LCDUI project and is able to start a LWUIT form from inside it by initializing LWUIT display. It may be the way to go.